# Hibernate: adding an object if not already present

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's the case: I am creating a batch script that runs daily, parsing logfiles and exporting the data to a database. The format of this file is basically

```
std_prop1;std_prop2;std_prop3;[opt_prop1;[opt_prop2;[opt_prop3;[..]]]
```

The standard properties map to a table with a column for each property, where each line in the logfile basically maps to a corresponding row. It might look like `LOGDATA(id,timestamp,systemId,methodName,callLenght)`. Since we should be able to log as many optional properties as we like, we cannot map them to the same table, since that would mean adding a row the table every time a new property was introduced. Not to think of the number of `NULL` references ...

So the additional properties go in another table, say `EXTRA_PROPS(logdata_foreign_key,propname,value)`. In reality, most of the optional properties are the same (e.g. os version, app container, etc), making it somewhat wasteful to log for instance 4 rows in EXTRA_PROPS for each row in LOGDATA (in the case that one on average had 4 extra properties). So what I would like my batch job to do is

```
for each additionalProperty in logRow:
  see if additionalProperty already exist
  if exists:
    create a reference to it in a reference table
  if not:
    add the property to the extra properties table
    create a reference to it in a reference table
```

I would then probably have three slightly different tables:

```
LOGDATA(id,timestamp,systemId,methodName,callLenght)
EXTRA_PROPS(id,propname,value)
LOGDATA_HAS_EXTRA_PROPS(logid,extra_prop_id)
```

I am not 100% this is a better way of doing it, I would still create N rows in the `LOGDATA_HAS_EXTRA_PROPS` table for N properties, but at least I would not add any new rows to `EXTRA_PROPS`.

Even if this might not be the best way (what is?), I am still wondering about the tecnhical side: How would I implement this using Hibernate? It does not have to be superfast, but it would need to chew through 100K+ rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would not recommend using Hibernate for this type of logic. Hibernate is a great product but doing this kind of high load data operations may not be it's strongest point.

From data modeling standpoint, it appears to me that `(propname,value)` is actually a primary key in `EXTRA_PROPS`. Basically, you want to express the logic that, for example, `hostname` + `foo.bar.com` combination will only appear once in the table. Am I right? That would be PK. So you will need to use that in `LOGDATA_HAS_EXTRA_PROPS`. Using `name` alone will not be sufficient for reference.

In Hibernate (if you choose to use it), that can be expressed via composite key using `@EmbeddedId` or `Embeddable` on object mapped to `EXTRA_PROPS`. And then you can have many to many relationship that uses `LOGDATA_HAS_EXTRA_PROPS` as association table.

Comment: Actually I have used Hibernate for this in development already. Worked fine and was done in a few seconds. I know that value+key is PK, but the Hibernate docs usually advices you to use syntetic keys anyway. Otherwise I could of course just done it in two tables. 
LOGDATA(id,timestamp,systemId,methodName,callLenght)
EXTRA_PROPS(log_id,propname,value)

Comment: But I still wonder about the answer to the original question ... :) Is all of the checking done automatically by Hibernate?

Comment: Synthetic or natural key is a big argument. Normally, I prefer synthetic keys, but in your use case it just does not add anything but complexity since you will need to search your EXTRA_PROPS table to see if you need to generate new id or use existing one. With natural key all job will be done by Hibernate. In any case, many-to-many will work. The only question I could see `How would I implement this using Hibernate?` and the answer is 'using many-to-many association regardless of what key you use'. Hibernate will take care of many details.

Comment: I have not got the time to check it out right now, but I am rewarding you the answer.